# Add/Remove all classes except event

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to remove all other classes except the eventarget in with JavaScript.

For example, if I have a UL:

```
<ul>
     <li>list element</li>
     <li>list element</li>
     <li>list element</li>
     <li>list element</li>
     <li>list element</li>
     <li>list element</li>
</ul>
```

And I add click event listener with an event handler:

```
var UL = document.querySelector('ul');

function eventHandler(e) {
    var thiz = e.target;
    document.querySelectorAll('ul li').classList.remove("active");
    thiz.classList.add("active");
}

UL.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    eventHandler(e);
});
```

How can I add a class on the element being clicked, while removing all the other "active" classes.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/298ZV/

Comment: within the event handler function, `this` refers to the element that triggered the event... so why not set the class directly to `this`?

Comment: Unrelated, but you can pass the callable of `eventHandler` directly into the listener, like so: `UL.addEventListener('click', eventHandler)` since they take the same arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without jQuery:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul li'), function(a){
    a.classList.remove('active');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/298ZV/1/).

This uses the `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate over the NodeList and executes the function on each element.

You could also 'simplify' (though do note the scare-quotes...) a little further and do *everything* within the same `forEach()`:

```
function eventHandler(e) {
    var thiz = e.target;
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul li'), function(a){
        a.classList[a == e.target ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
    });
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/298ZV/2/).

With regards to concerns expressd by @adeneo, in [comments to his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872550/add-remove-all-classes-except-event#comment36746384_23872587), that should the `li` elements contain other elements they will become the `event.target` I've added a *simple* `closest()` function to find the element you're looking for:

```
var UL = document.querySelector('ul');

function closest(origin, elem) {
    var current = origin;
    elem = elem.toLowerCase();
    while (current.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'body' && current.tagName.toLowerCase() !== elem) {
        current = current.parentNode;
    }
    return current;
}

function eventHandler(e) {
    var that = closest(e.target, 'li');
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul li'), function(a) {
        a.classList[that === a ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
    });
}

UL.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    eventHandler(e);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/298ZV/3/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

Comment: I love `forEach`! Just note it's [unavailable before IE 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility). Also, this doesn't exclude the current node

Comment: can't you just  use e.target.tagName and then e.target.parentNode instead? That's what I'm doing.

Comment: Is that to find the `li` element-node? Because if it *is* then I'd rather use the function I added, since it frees me from having to navigate to specific points in the ancestry which, over time, gets ridiculous (and yes, I have tried `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode`... before now, and having learned better I will never do that again).

Answer (score 1):

Do it a little differently, attach the event handler to the LI's, and keep them in a variable, then iterate over the LI's and remove the class from the ones that aren't `this`

```
var LI = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');

for (var i=LI.length; i--;) {
    LI[i].addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
}

function eventHandler() {
    this.className = 'active';

    for (var i=LI.length; i--;) {
        if (LI[i] != this) LI[i].className = '';
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Cgq/)

Comment: I think that would be (however neglectfully) slower, also not as easy to do

Comment: @ChenAsraf - that's probably true, but the problem with the OP's code is that it relies on the event.target, and has the event handler on a different element than what is actually clicked. The OP will notice this the second the LI contains another element, and the event.target is suddenly something else.

Comment: They could use `this` directly there in that case, since you used `this` as well...

Comment: I can use `this` as the event handler is attached to the LI, the OP can't as `this` would be the UL, so the OP has to use `event.target`, which is fine, until you add a span or anchor inside the LI, and you're screwed as the `event.target` is no longer the LI.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice the different targets, but in that case they should just attach the listener to the `li` and not `ul`

Comment: @ChenAsraf - That's what I just said in my answer ?

Comment: Yes :) just no need for the loop

Comment: @adeneo if you know there could be a other elements like a span inside the element you can just do "var tag = e.target.tagName; if (event.target == 'span') { e.target = e.target.parentNode)}